# ScrollView makes buttons less responsive

Tags: java, android, xml, android-scrollview

I tried to implement a ScrollView on one of my activities' xml. I'm noticing a glaring issue: the buttons, which are snappy and responsive, suddenly have noticable delay after the ScrollView is added. I'm currently working off a Nexus 10, so I doubt it's a performance problem.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:context=".SomeActivity" >

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout_contact"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background= "@drawable/formbox">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/textEmployeeName" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout_options"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/layout_contact">

                <Button android:id="@+id/optionsTime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_selection"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/header1"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/optionsTime"
                    android:background="@drawable/formheader"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/options1"
                    android:layout_width = "200dp"
                    android:layout_height= "100dp"
                    android:textSize= "22sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/togglebutton_9patch"
                    android:layout_below="@id/header1"
                    android:textOn="1"
                    android:textOff="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Is there anything I can do either from the XML or by programming to make the buttons interact seamlessly again?

Comment: would adding "android:fillViewport="true"" and/or "android:clipChildren="false"" to the scrollView  help?

Comment: Not really. The delay is there all the same. There isn't any lag persay when I scroll. It's just that the added delay on button press is annoying and makes the application feel less responsive, even though it unmistakenly still activates the buttons when I touch them.

Comment: xml seems fine. have you tried other layouts too?

Comment: As in LinearLayout instead of Relative?

Comment: yes, have you tried linearLayout?

Comment: Bit of an old question, and I'm not an android dev, but for those who stumble on this via google; in iOS scrollViews add a delay to content touches, which gives the user enough time to scroll the view before activating any of it's subviews. Perhaps something similar is happening here.